# shell script mysql output transformation

Tags: mysql, regex, shell

i have a script to synchronize/output my mysql database with another server.

i know how to call this SQL query in shell. however, is it possible to convert this script's output from php to shell script to keep the format shown below (basically values separated by "|" and some URLs)? i need the output in this specific format shown below:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT a, b, c, d, e FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB USING (a)");

while ($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
              {
                echo $res['a']."|".$res['b']."|".$res['c']."|http://www.url.com/".$res['e']."/".$res['a'].".php|http://www.url.com/link/".urlencode($res['b'])."\n";
              }
```

thanks

Comment: shell scripts aren't going to make it easy for you to talk to a database. Just turn your php script into a shell script (add `#!/usr/bin/php` at the top and make it executable.

Comment: really great advice too marc! makes my life much more simple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all these concatenation with a simple Query passed to mysql from command line :

```
mysql -u username -ppassword -D dbname << eof
SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,PIPES_AS_CONCAT';
SELECT a || '|' || b || '|' || c || '|http://www.url.com/' || e || '/' || a || '.php|http://www.url.com/link/' || b AS joinedColum FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB USING (a);
eof
```

The first SET, set the pipe as concat operator in MySQL so you can join string with SQL standard double pipe instead of using the annoying CONCAT function ... After that the result set is a concatenation of strings directly in the SQL query. 
In this way you can execute this command from a bash script without the necessity to have a php interpreter installed ...

Comment: awesome advice, havent even knew thats possible. thanks a lot.